# INSERT data from one table to another where ids match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
1. `blog_export`: 'id', 'body'. 
'id' already has values 'body' is empty. 

2. `field_data_body`: 'body_value','entity_id'
```

I would like to copy `body_value` from `field_data_body` and insert that data into the column 'body' on the table `blog_export` but ONLY where 'id' matches 'entity_id'

I have the statement

```
INSERT INTO `blog_export` (`body`)
SELECT `body_value`
FROM `field_data_body`
WHERE `bundle` = 'wp_blog' AND `entity_id` = `blog_export`.`id`
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: you mean UPDATE right ? It's an Update with a Join

Comment: `insert` is for inserting new rows. You are looking for `update`, which updates fields of existing rows to a new value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update from Select with Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916186/update-from-select-with-join)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15209489/1816093

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to perform an `UPDATE` operation instead joining with other table like

```
UPDATE `blog_export` be
JOIN `field_data_body` fdb ON fdb.`entity_id` = be.`id`
SET be.`body` = fdb.`body_value`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your current situation with your tables, you have at least these two options.

1) `blog_export` *already has records for all the records* with possible `entity_id` values in `field_data_body`. In this case, you just need to update all the records and you can simply use an update statement (instead of your insert), as others already recommended.

Either use the multiple-table syntax (just as in Rahul's answer):

```
UPDATE blog_export be
JOIN field_data_body fdb ON fdb.entity_id = be.id
SET be.body = fdb.body_value;
```

Or the single-table syntax:

```
UPDATE blog_export be
SET body = (SELECT body FROM field_data_body WHERE entity_id = be.id);
```

2) `blog_export` *does not contain all the records* with possible `entity_id` values in `field_data_body` (i.e. none of them, or maybe just a subset of them). In this case, you must insert new records to the table and update already existing ones.

You can use an insert statement with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause (supposing that `blog_export.id` is `unique` or `primary key`):

```
INSERT INTO blog_export (id, body)
SELECT entity_id, body_value
FROM field_data_body
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE body=body_value;
```